# how to pass angular variable in laravel method in view

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I'm trying to pass angular variable into static method loaded in my view from my laravel controller

```
my view:
use \App\Http\Controllers\SomeController;

{{SomeController::check(history.referenceno)}}

my.variable is a angular variable. but it's showing me error 
Use of undefined constant history
```

this is a table

```
<tr ng-repeat="history in data.bills">
    <td class="ng-cloak min-w-td" style="text-align:center;"></td>
    <td class="ng-cloak min-w-td" style="text-align:center;">@{{history.referenceno}}</td>
    <td class="ng-cloak min-w-td" style="text-align:center;">@{{history.category}}</td>
    <td class="ng-cloak min-w-td" style="text-align:center;">@{{history.productCode}}</td>
    <td class="ng-cloak min-w-td" style="text-align:center;">@{{history.amount | number : 0}}</td>
    <td class="ng-cloak min-w-td" style="text-align:center;">{{SomeController::verify(history.referenceno)}}</td>
    <td class="ng-cloak min-w-td" style="text-align:center;">@{{history.datecreated}}</td>
    </tr>
```

I want to access the my.variable and read it to the static function check

Comment: Please share the error with us .

Comment: Use of undefined constant history - assumed 'history' i mentioned it above.

Comment: You can't pass an angular variable to Laravel like that since Angular is working only on the client side and PHP on the server.  You need to write some sort of ajax call back to the server and pass that variable.

Comment: how? can i pass it via ajax?